Cannot place whatIfOrder with ib_insync
I'm trying to place a what-if-order with ib_insync, but I get an error related to asyncio's event loop when calling whatIfOrder:

This event loop is already running.

Placing regular orders instead of what-if-orders works. The following example reproduces the situation.
from ib_insync import IB, Forex, Ticker, MarketOrder


def on_tick(ticker: Ticker):
    o = MarketOrder("BUY", 10000)
    res = ib.whatIfOrder(contract, o) # => ERROR


ib = IB()
ib.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=4001, clientId=1)
contract = Forex('GBPUSD', 'IDEALPRO')
ib.qualifyContracts(contract)
ticker = ib.reqMktData(contract)
ticker.updateEvent += on_tick
ib.run()

It seems like ib.run() starts the event loop (with loop.run_forever()), but then  loop.is_running() is false. I don't know what is going on.

The ib.whatIfOrder() is blocking and tries to start a new loop (see here https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/_modules/ib_insync/ib.html#IB.whatIfOrder).
Instead of using the blocking version, use the asynchronous one:
from ib_insync import IB, Forex, Ticker, MarketOrder


async def on_tick(ticker: Ticker):
    o = MarketOrder("BUY", 10000)
    try:
        res = await ib.whatIfOrderAsync(contract, o)  # use the async version
        # do something with res
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")


ib = IB()
ib.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=4001, clientId=1)
contract = Forex('GBPUSD', 'IDEALPRO')
ib.qualifyContracts(contract)
ticker = ib.reqMktData(contract)
ticker.updateEvent += on_tick
ib.run()

